# Split multiline text into multiple rows - NiFi/Kafka

Tags: apache-nifi

I have an input multiline text like this:

```
"offset":3780214, "message":@ 2022-05-23 12:25:39.879 [    30] [lap=126.18  uS]       Out of range"offset":3780940, "message":@ 2022-05-23 12:25:39.879 [    30] [lap=106.46  uS]       Execution finished unexpectedly.
+Exception message:
+################################################
+#   BEGIN                       #
+################################################
+   Error
+################################################
+#   END                         #
+################################################"
```

I can also remove the offset, if it's better for you:

```
"message":@ 2022-05-23 12:25:39.879 [    30] [lap=126.18  uS]       Out of range"message":@ 2022-05-23 12:25:39.879 [    30] [lap=106.46  uS]       Execution finished unexpectedly.
+Exception message:
+################################################
+#   BEGIN                       #
+################################################
+   Error
+################################################
+#   END                         #
+################################################"
```

I want to split that text in multiple lines, delimited by "message", like this:

Row 1: `@ 2022-05-23 12:25:39.879 [    30] [lap=126.18  uS]       Out of range`

Row 2:

```
+Exception message:
+################################################
+#   BEGIN                       #
+################################################
+   Error
+################################################
+#   END                         #
+################################################"
```

I tried to do that with the [SplitContent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8A3Z.png) but it returns the first row multiple times, like this:

`@ 2022-05-23 12:25:39.879 [    30] [lap=126.18  uS]       Out of range`

`@ 2022-05-23 12:25:39.879 [    30] [lap=126.18  uS]       Out of range`

`@ 2022-05-23 12:25:39.879 [    30] [lap=126.18  uS]       Out of range`

`@ 2022-05-23 12:25:39.879 [    30] [lap=126.18  uS]       Out of range`

Comment: Still think your input is messed up. You have `"offset": X, "message": "..."` twice on the same lines. Ideally, those would be two completely separate NiFi events

Comment: They are separate events, but I need to write everything in the same line because I'm using just 1 partition. I think that there should be an option to use "message" as a delimiter, without taking into account if it's a newline or not

Comment: I think we are using the word "event" differently. Yes, I see they have unique data, but they should be two different flowfiles, with two unique offset/message attributes, and not on the "same line". Which they **should be** already, if the input (kafka consumer) was reading them as separate (kafka) records.

Comment: OK, so you say to keep only the "message" in this flowfile and have one row for each event?

Comment: What you are going to do with two different file contents after this?

Comment: I just need the "message". After this, I have to apply a 2nd filter and plot this information in different topics in Grafana. I don't know if I need Logstand and/or Elasticsearch

Comment: Grafana needs a datasource, such as Elasticsearch, or you could write the data to a SQL database instead like Postgres. Logstash is also able to read files on disk, or [from filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/logstash-output.html), then parse/or and split these events without needing to use Nifi or Kafka.